# Missing data in Python nested loop

Tags: python, math, physics

I'm working with a multidimensional data array where I have various data points for individuals.  I created a nested loop that allows me to make metric calculations throughout the entire dataset, however, once rearranging it I loose data points. From my initial 253 individuals, I end up with the calculated metrics for 182. The code works, but I don't know at which moment I'm letting data out.

```
data_array -- containing 253 individuals, each with several subcategories 

mos0_ids=[]
mos0_dt = []
mos0_x_dpos = []
mos0_y_dpos = []
mos0_z_dpos = []

for i in range (0,252): 
    mos0=data_array[i]
    mos0_id= mos0[0][0]                                                                             
    mos0_time=mos0[:,1]                                                                                      
    mos0_x_pos=mos0[:,2]
    mos0_y_pos=mos0[:,3]
    mos0_z_pos=mos0[:,4]
    mos0_speed=mos0[:,6]

    for j in range(0,len(mos0_id)):  
        mos0_ids.append(mos0_id)
        
    for k in range(0,len(mos0_time)):
        first_mov_time=mos0_time[k]
        last_mov_time=mos0_time[k-1]
        first_movement = dt.datetime.strptime(first_mov_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
        last_movement = dt.datetime.strptime(last_mov_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
        x = first_movement - last_movement
        total_seconds = x.total_seconds()  
        mos0_dt.append(total_seconds)
    
    for l in range(0,len(mos0_x_pos)):
        first_mov_pos=mos0_x_pos[l]
        last_mov_pos=mos0_x_pos[l-1]
        x = first_mov_pos - last_mov_pos
        mos0_x_dpos.append(x)
    
    for m in range(0,len(mos0_y_pos)):
        first_mov_pos=mos0_y_pos[m]
        last_mov_pos=mos0_y_pos[m-1]
        x = first_mov_pos - last_mov_pos
        mos0_y_dpos.append(x)
    
    for n in range(0,len(mos0_z_pos)):
        first_mov_pos=mos0_z_pos[n]
        last_mov_pos=mos0_z_pos[n-1]
        x = first_mov_pos - last_mov_pos
        mos0_z_dpos.append(x)
        
mos0_ids
mos0_dt
mos0_x_dpos 
mos0_y_dpos 
mos0_z_dpos       

time_pos=list(zip(mos0_ids, mos0_dt, mos0_x_dpos, mos0_y_dpos, mos0_z_dpos))                                                 
time_pos=pd.DataFrame(time_pos,columns=['mos_id','dtime', 'x_position', 'y_position','z_position'])               #  transform into a dataframe         
time_pos['x_velocity'] = time_pos['x_position']/time_pos['dtime']
time_pos['y_velocity'] = time_pos['y_position']/time_pos['dtime']
time_pos['z_velocity'] = time_pos['z_position']/time_pos['dtime']

time_pos['x_acceleration'] = time_pos['x_velocity']/time_pos['dtime']
time_pos['y_acceleration'] = time_pos['y_velocity']/time_pos['dtime']
time_pos['z_acceleration'] = time_pos['z_velocity']/time_pos['dtime']

time_pos=time_pos.groupby('mos_id')
time_pos = np.array(time_pos, dtype=object)    
time_pos
```

EDIT:

I re arranged the code as to including `for i in range (0,253)` and including an indent as following:

```
for i in range (0,253): 
    mos0=swarm_data_array[i]
    mos0_id= mos0[0][0]                                                                             
    mos0_time=mos0[:,1]                                                                                      
    mos0_x_pos=mos0[:,2]
    mos0_y_pos=mos0[:,3]
    mos0_z_pos=mos0[:,4]
    mos0_speed=mos0[:,6]    
    
    for j in range(len(mos0_id)):  
        mos0_ids.append(mos0_id)
        
        for k in range(len(mos0_time)):
            first_mov_time=mos0_time[k]
            last_mov_time=mos0_time[k-1]
            first_movement = dt.datetime.strptime(first_mov_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
            last_movement = dt.datetime.strptime(last_mov_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
            x = first_movement - last_movement
            total_seconds = x.total_seconds()  
            mos0_dt.append(total_seconds)
                
        for l in range(len(mos0_x_pos)):
            first_mov_pos=mos0_x_pos[l]
            last_mov_pos=mos0_x_pos[l-1]
            x = first_mov_pos - last_mov_pos
            mos0_x_dpos.append(x)
        
        for m in range(len(mos0_y_pos)):
            first_mov_pos=mos0_y_pos[m]
            last_mov_pos=mos0_y_pos[m-1]
            x = first_mov_pos - last_mov_pos
            mos0_y_dpos.append(x)
        
        for n in range(len(mos0_z_pos)):
            first_mov_pos=mos0_z_pos[n]
            last_mov_pos=mos0_z_pos[n-1]
            x = first_mov_pos - last_mov_pos
            mos0_z_dpos.append(x)

mos0_ids
mos0_dt
mos0_x_dpos 
mos0_y_dpos 
mos0_z_dpos       

time_pos=list(zip(mos0_ids, mos0_dt, mos0_x_dpos, mos0_y_dpos, mos0_z_dpos))                                                 
time_pos=pd.DataFrame(time_pos,columns=['mos_id','dtime', 'x_position', 'y_position','z_position'])               #  transform into a dataframe         
time_pos['x_velocity'] = time_pos['x_position']/time_pos['dtime']
time_pos['y_velocity'] = time_pos['y_position']/time_pos['dtime']
time_pos['z_velocity'] = time_pos['z_position']/time_pos['dtime']

time_pos['x_acceleration'] = time_pos['x_velocity']/time_pos['dtime']
time_pos['y_acceleration'] = time_pos['y_velocity']/time_pos['dtime']
time_pos['z_acceleration'] = time_pos['z_velocity']/time_pos['dtime']

time_pos=time_pos.groupby('mos_id')
```

The issue now is that after I organize my data using GroupBy and I apply a .describe() function, I'm left with a constant 26 count per group and this is not correct. There are groups larger than others. Could this be an error in any part of the nested loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably miss one "specific" behavior of range().
Your first very simplified loop will have only `252` values, instead of having `253`


Try this out in console:

`len(range(0,252))` -> 252

So I presume as it's nested arr (matrices), it looses lots of data according to several calculations it should make for every col/row.
Solution:

`for i in range(0, 253)` or `for i in range(len(data_array) + 1)`

I assume same happened to all of your provided `for` loops

Comment: Thanks! I used the ```for i in range(0, 253)``` but still was missing data points. I arranged the nested loop by indenting from line 17 onwards and now I have the dataset I needed!